# Replacement rule for a function and its derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

I have this equation:

```
  EOM1 = Subscript[x1, t, t] + ω1^2*x1 /. 
    Subscript[x1_, m__] :> D[x1[x, t], m] /. 
      x1 -> x1[x, t]
```

The problem with the rule is that it doubles the argument. How can I avoid writing the arguments `[x,t]` twice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
 EOM1 = Subscript[x1, t, t] + \[Omega]1^2*x1[x, t] /. 
   Subscript[x1_, m__] :> D[x1[x, t], m] /. x1 -> x1[x, t] /. x1[x, t] -> x1
```

[image: Output expression]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your meaning, but if write

```
EOM1 = Subscript[x1, t, t] + ω1^2*x1 /. 
Subscript[x1_, m__] :> D[x1[x, t], m] /. 
  x1 -> x1
```

you obtain

```
x1 \[Omega]1^2+(x1^(0,2))[x,t]
```